# Validating and Validated event of DatePicker

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Kindly let me know what equavalent of "Validating and Validated" event of "DatePicker" in WPF.

Any suggestion will highly welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Date picker validation WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610883/date-picker-validation-wpf).

You need to use a validation rule, which then has a validate function.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have DatePicker in my application I am binding this control Text property from my string Property define in viewModel. I want user to enter date in any format (e.g '01012012'). As user tab out from this control it display me in '01/01/2012' format. I have implemented logic for that but the problem is that when I tab out from this control I don't get entered text as this control display me default date e.g '1/1/0001', So kindly let me how I get entered value and set it from viewmodel.

Comment: If you are binding to a property in your viewmodel, you should be able to put do something like    {Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"   and then be notified in the PropertyChanged event in your viewmodel. You can then check to see if the field is valid and put your custom logic in there. Those changes should then be pushed back to your control via the 2 way binding