# how to disable past days in calender in WPF?

Tags: wpf

i'm developing WPF application in that i'm trying to disable the past days in calender.
any way is there to disable the past days.please let me know.

thanks

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: You can use the DisplayDateStart and DisplayDateEnd properties of DatePicker

Comment: I'm not sure about disabling but what you could do is validate the datepicker based on the selected date. Take a lookn at this link here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610883/date-picker-validation-wpf Hope this helps

Comment: hi Danny Beckett: in calender we can block the dates by mentioning from date to date by like this:                                   <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="01/01/2010" End="01/06/2010" />
        <CalendarDateRange Start="05/01/2010" End="05/03/2010" />
</Calendar.BlackoutDates>                                                     me don't have start date only have end date as yesterday, i need to block the past dates.

Comment: like to do in calender not in datepicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution by trying myself.

In `Window_load` just add this line for `calendar`.

```
Caldate.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(1990, 1, 1), 
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));
```

It will block previous dates.

Comment: This will mean the user can choose any date before 1990 as well.

Comment: Then you can set it to some date completely out of reach: DatePickerName.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(1, 1, 1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));

Comment: `Calendar.BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast()`. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendarblackoutdatescollection.adddatesinpast(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 18):

You have to set the `DisplayDateStart` attribute with Today's date

```
<DatePicker Name="dt_StartDateFrom" DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}">
</DatePicker>
```

Make sure you have set the

> xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

in your `<UserControl>` tag to be able to use the `sys:` parameter

P.S. To Disable future dates, you can use `DisplayDateEnd` attribute

Answer (score 13):

You can set the [DisplayDateStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydatestart%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to today.

```
myCalendar.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Today;
```

Instead of hiding all previous values, if you want to black them out, you can do this.

```
CalendarDateRange cdr = new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Today);
myCalendar.BlackoutDates.Add(cdr);
```

Comment: you are right, but i like to show the dates as crossed without disappearing the dates.

Comment: how  to set a  fixed  date  instead  of   today  date ??

Comment: @Kartiikeya - See the example in the `DisplayDateStart` link. You can create a new `DateTime` object and pass in the date you want.

Comment: how  to  disable  day  view  in  datepicker  UI ?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the past days in calender in this way : -

**Caldr.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Today;**

Answer (score 2):

To block out the past dates (everything before today), you can simply use the Framework's 4.0+ method : AddDatesInPast()

```
myCalendar.BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast();
```

It does the same as the accepted answer but is more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30213551) is a neater solution to the problem in case we want to add it through xaml.

Answer (score 1):

I like a @sohailby answer but I just want to change little by using blackoutdates

```
  <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
     <CalendarDateRange End="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" Start="{x:Static sys:DateTime.MinValue}" />
  </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF and you want to use MVVM binding to your view model. This approach is more general and lets you do boundary checking within your unit tests.

```
   <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"  DisplayDateStart="{Binding MinAvailDate}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding MaxAvailDate}"></DatePicker>
```

In the view model....

```
private DateTime _minAvailDate= DateTime.UtcNow;
        public DateTime MinAvailDate { get { return _minAvailDate; }
        set { _minAvailDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("MinAvailDate"); }
```

Set MinAvailDate = DateTime.Now, or adjust the default for  your time zone.
Implement MaxAvailDate in a similar way, as well as you binding to the SelectedDate.