# WPF : How to remove the red border in DatePickerTextBox?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datepicker, border

I was searching for a solution during the previous hour but I didn't find.

My problem is just that I want to disable the red border when my textbox is empty. I don't really want to disable validationError even if I tried too but it was also a big failure. I really don't know how to do this.

If one knows please, I will be your servant for all my life (or almost :))

Thanks !

My DatePicker (I don't know if it's usefull)

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=RuleItem.Type, Converter={StaticResource RecurringRuleToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Inverted}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=ActiveTo, Converter={StaticResource DatesRuleToSelectedDatePickerConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, ValidatesOnExceptions=False}"
                    SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                    DisplayDateStart="{Binding Path=ActiveTo, Converter={StaticResource SelectedDateToStartEndDatePickerConverter}, ConverterParameter=Start}"
                    DisplayDateEnd="{Binding Path=ActiveTo, Converter={StaticResource SelectedDateToStartEndDatePickerConverter}, ConverterParameter=End}" 
                    FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"
                    Width="130">
        </DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this within your control

```
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
```

Like this:

```
<igWPF:XamDateTimeEditor  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"  AutoFillDate="MonthAndYear" Text="{Binding SelectedToDate,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsToDatePickerEnabled}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but here is a possible solution. In the `DatePickerTextBox` within the `ControlTemplate` of the `DatePicker` (or whatever `TextBox` is there, if you replaced it), set the property `Validation.ErrorTemplate` to `{x:Null}`. Keep in mind this will prevent all of the validations from working (if it has any others; never looked into that but for my purposes this worked just fine since I didn't want any, anyway), not just that one that creates the red border on empty text.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own validation rule including Text.Empty as not an error. For writing validation rule refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610883/date-picker-validation-wpf).

Comment: Infine, I found an other solution. First : I made the binding on SelectedDate and not on Text (it changes lot of things) with a DateTime? property. Then I implemented the convert back method which return null if there is no date. Because the property accepts the value null, there is no error for the control and I don't have  anymore the red border \o/